# ошибка SIGSEGV, в чем проблема?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

функция обработки `point`, координат курсора

```
void Grid::receiver_item(QPoint point)
{
    item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item = table->itemAt(point);
    int x = item->row();
    qDebug()<< x;
 }
```

Переопределил функцию `mousePressEvent`  в классе `QTableWidget`, по правому клику мыши пытаюсь получить информацию о ячейке на которой находится курсор. Запускаю программу, кликаю правой кнопкой мыши и возникает SIGSEGV, гугл говорит, что обращаюсь несуществующий указатель, и я как-то не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: Я не спец в Qt, но вот это - `item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item = table->itemAt(point);` - откровенно смущает. Создали что-то через `new` и тут же его забыли?..

Comment: т.е. как забыли?..

Comment: В этом коде есть утечка памяти, память под `item` выделяется и тут же в этот же указатель записывается значение из `itemAt`. Первая строчка тут попросту лишняя. Замечу, что `itemAt` может вернуть `nullptr` если под указателем мыши нет никаких элементов (items)

Comment: @АнтонСимаков А где после второй строчки хранится указатель на вновь созданный `QTableWidgetItem`? Нет, я не спорю, можно написать конструктор так, что он будет сохранять адрес где-то в каком-то глобальном списке... но вряд ли так сделано реально.

Answer (score 1):

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = table->itemAt(point);

if(item != nullptr) {
    int x = item->row();
    qDebug()<< x;
}
```